# Error Running NUnit Tests in TFS Build

Tags: .net, automated-tests, nunit, tfsbuild, nunittestadapter

I have a build in which one of the steps is to run Unit tests

In my test project I have:
NUnit v3.4.1
NUnitTestAdapter: 2.0.0

My test step is setup as follows
[image]

I get the following exception

**Error: Exception NUnit.Core.UnsupportedFrameworkException, Exception thrown executing tests**

Comment: The version of NUnit and NUnitTestAdapter is incompatible. As you have NUnit 3.x.y you need to install NUnit3TestAdapter to make version compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i removed NUnitTestAdapter 2.0

and added NUnit3TestAdapter

and it now works